# ATR calculation in ta library seems not consistent

Tags: python, ta-lib

First a disclaimer: I'm a beginner in programming, and in python, so apologies if below is a super basic error on my part.

I encountered a strange behavior the other day when calculating the ATR. I cleaned up my code to simplify it, in order to post it here, so please see below for the code I use.

====

```
import pandas as pd
import ta.volatility
import time
import ccxt
import datetime as dt

# set the maximum number of columns to be displayed
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)


def ohlcv_cctx(exchange, symbol, timeframe, duration):

    end_timestamp = int(dt.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)
    start_timestamp = end_timestamp - (duration * 60 * 60 * 1000)

    ohlcv = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe=timeframe, since=start_timestamp, limit=duration)

    df = pd.DataFrame(ohlcv, columns=['Datetime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
    df = df.iloc[:-1, :]
    df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], unit='ms')

    df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)  # Set 'Datetime' as the index

    return df

def atr(df):  # define ATR values

    high = pd.Series(df.High)
    low = pd.Series(df.Low)
    close = pd.Series(df.Close)

    atr_ = ta.volatility.average_true_range(high, low, close, window=14)

    return atr_


# Define function to fetch 1-minute candles
def ohlcv_1min():
    # Collect price data
    prices_1min = ohlcv_cctx(exchange_name, 'BTC/EUR', '1m', 60)

    # Calculate the ATR values
    atr1 = atr(prices_1min)

    # Extend the df with ATR column
    prices_1min.loc[:, 'ATR'] = atr1
    prices_1min = prices_1min[prices_1min['ATR'] != 0]

    return prices_1min


exchange_name = ccxt.binance()

while True:     # run in endless loop

    prices = ohlcv_1min()

    print(prices.tail(5))

    # sleep time is 1 minute
    print(f'Waiting for about 1 minute...')
    time.sleep(60)
```

===

It fetches an OHLCV dataframe every minute, with minute candle bars. Each df is 60 minutes long (so 60 rows). Also, the ATR is calculated with a period of 14, and added to the df as a new column.

The strange thing is that the ATR value seems to vary in subsequent dfs. See below the result of 3 minutes running this code, and follow for example the ATR value for **2023-07-25 22:40:00**.

I would expect the value to be the same, but it is not. In my understanding the calculation uses the high/low/close values of the previous 14 rows, and those do not change. So how come the ATR value itself is different in each df?

Is my understanding of the ATR calculation wrong? Is my code incorrect? Or is something weird happening in the calculation?

In the first run, the ATR value for 22:40:00 is:     2.984393
In the second run, the ATR value for 22:40:00 is:    2.982639
In the third run, the ATR value for 22:40:00 is:     2.946261

```
                         Open      High       Low     Close   Volume       ATR
Datetime                                                                      
2023-07-25 22:37:00  26537.03  26538.20  26537.03  26538.19  0.43921  3.162514
2023-07-25 22:38:00  26538.19  26540.32  26538.19  26540.32  0.11223  3.088763
2023-07-25 22:39:00  26542.89  26542.90  26540.86  26540.87  0.12402  3.052423
2023-07-25 22:40:00  26540.86  26540.87  26538.77  26538.77  0.19598  2.984393 <==
2023-07-25 22:41:00  26538.77  26538.77  26535.00  26535.01  0.13674  3.040508
Waiting for about 1 minute...
                         Open      High       Low     Close   Volume       ATR
Datetime                                                                      
2023-07-25 22:38:00  26538.19  26540.32  26538.19  26540.32  0.11223  3.086730
2023-07-25 22:39:00  26542.89  26542.90  26540.86  26540.87  0.12402  3.050535
2023-07-25 22:40:00  26540.86  26540.87  26538.77  26538.77  0.19598  2.982639 <==
2023-07-25 22:41:00  26538.77  26538.77  26535.00  26535.01  0.13674  3.038879
2023-07-25 22:42:00  26535.01  26540.23  26535.00  26540.23  0.04023  3.195388
Waiting for about 1 minute...
                         Open      High       Low     Close   Volume       ATR
Datetime                                                                      
2023-07-25 22:39:00  26542.89  26542.90  26540.86  26540.87  0.12402  3.011358
2023-07-25 22:40:00  26540.86  26540.87  26538.77  26538.77  0.19598  2.946261 <==
2023-07-25 22:41:00  26538.77  26538.77  26535.00  26535.01  0.13674  3.005100
2023-07-25 22:42:00  26535.01  26540.23  26535.00  26540.23  0.04023  3.164021
2023-07-25 22:43:00  26540.22  26540.22  26538.80  26538.80  0.00531  3.040163
Waiting for about 1 minute...
```

Note:
I checked the input of the function ATR, but this seems to be correct. I checked what happens on Tradingview, and the ATR value stays constant for a certain timestamp, as I expected according to my understanding of the ATR calculation.